# C# Deserialize XML to object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, deserialization

Having problems deserializing some xml into an object in C#.

The error that I receive is...

```
xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

The XSD that I received to generate my class is as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="xml.AAAAAAA.com/commerce/apres-vente_technique/assistance" xmlns:pgp="xml.AAAAAAA.com/commerce/apres-vente_technique/assistance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="ListeAvisRemboursements">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Liste des avis de remboursements</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="AvisRemboursement" type="pgp:AvisRemboursementType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="AvisRemboursementType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Avis de remboursement lié à une DC</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
```

(snipped)

The file that I am attempting to import is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListeAvisRemboursements xmlns:ast="xml.AAAAAAA.com/commerce/apres-vente_technique/assistance">
    <ast:AvisRemboursement NumeroDT="3826961" CodeRA="020545G01" NumeroDC="1">
        <ast:DateTraitement>2010-06-22</ast:DateTraitement>
        <ast:MontantDC>25.0</ast:MontantDC>
        <ast:MontantMO>0.0</ast:MontantMO>
        <ast:SommeAD>25.0</ast:SommeAD>
        <ast:MontantPR>0.0</ast:MontantPR>
        <ast:SommePR>0.0</ast:SommePR>
        <ast:FraisGestion>0.0</ast:FraisGestion>
        <ast:NombreHeuresTotalRemboursees>0</ast:NombreHeuresTotalRemboursees>
        <ast:Etat>C</ast:Etat>
        <ast:NoteCredit>319984</ast:NoteCredit>
        <ast:Imputation>030</ast:Imputation>
        <ast:ListInterventionsPR/>
        <ast:ListInterventionsMO/>
    </ast:AvisRemboursement>
```

(snipped)

I *think* what is happening is that when .Net attempts to derserialize the xml, it hits the first line which contains the "xmlns:ast" and complaints about it. As I understand it, .Net will try to map attributes to a public property in the target class (and it wont find one called xmlns. Or there is something wrong with how I am handling the name spaces.

My deserialization code looks as follows:

```
    XmlDocument _Doc = new XmlDocument();
    _Doc.Load(@"C:\inputfile.xml");

    XmlSerializer _XMLSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListeAvisRemboursements));
    ListeAvisRemboursements _X = (ListeAvisRemboursements)_XMLSer.Deserialize(new StringReader(_Doc.OuterXml));
```

I have also tried various combinations of adding a namespace manager to the XML document..

```
XmlNamespaceManager _Ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(_Doc.NameTable);
_Ns.AddNamespace("ast", "xml.AAAAAAA.com/commerce/apres-vente_technique/assistance");
```

I understand there is a way I can use this to tell .Net what namespaces to accept.

Would be greatful for some help iwth this problem.

--- Updated at request with class snippet (sorry should have included before) this was created with xsd.exe ---

```
 /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "xml.AAAAAAA.com/commerce/apres-vente_technique/assistance")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "xml.AAAAAAA.com/commerce/apres-vente_technique/assistance", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class ListeAvisRemboursements
    {

        private AvisRemboursementType[] avisRemboursementField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("AvisRemboursement")]
        public AvisRemboursementType[] AvisRemboursement
        {
            get
            {
                return this.avisRemboursementField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.avisRemboursementField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "xml.AAAAAAA.com/commerce/apres-vente_technique/assistance")]
    public partial class AvisRemboursementType
    {

        private System.DateTime dateTraitementField;

        private double montantDCField;

        private double montantMOField;

        private double sommeADField;

        private double montantPRField;
```

Comment: could you please post the snippet of your ListeAvisRemboursements class...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without a full xsd / xml, or (alternatively) your C# classes, we can't reproduce. But working from the xml upwards, this works fine for me; meaning: the error is not (as far as I can see) in the code/data you posted. Can you post a more complete (reproducible) example?

```
public class ListeAvisRemboursements
{
    private readonly List<AvisRemboursement> items = new List<AvisRemboursement>();
    [XmlElement("AvisRemboursement", Namespace = "xml.AAAAAAA.com/commerce/apres-vente_technique/assistance")]
    public List<AvisRemboursement> Items { get { return items; } }
}
public class AvisRemboursement
{
    [XmlAttribute] public string NumeroDT {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute] public string CodeRA {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute] public string NumeroDC {get;set;}
    public DateTime DateTraitement { get; set; }
    public decimal MontantDC { get; set; }
    public decimal MontantMO { get; set; }
    public decimal SommeAD { get; set; }
    public decimal MontantPR { get; set; }
    public decimal SommePR { get; set; }
    public decimal FraisGestion { get; set; }
    public int NombreHeuresTotalRemboursees { get; set; }
    public string Etat { get; set; }
    public string NoteCredit { get; set; }
    public string Imputation { get; set; }
}
static void Main()
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListeAvisRemboursements));
    var wrapper = (ListeAvisRemboursements)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
    // inspect wrapper.Items etc
}
```

also works fine with:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListeAvisRemboursements));
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("inputfile.xml"))
{
    var wrapper = (ListeAvisRemboursements)ser.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

and:

```
XmlDocument _Doc = new XmlDocument();
_Doc.Load("inputfile.xml");
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListeAvisRemboursements));
var wrapper = (ListeAvisRemboursements)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(_Doc.OuterXml));
```

and

```
XmlDocument _Doc = new XmlDocument();
_Doc.Load("inputfile.xml");
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListeAvisRemboursements));
var wrapper = (ListeAvisRemboursements)ser.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(_Doc.DocumentElement));
```

Comment: The problem was tracked down to incorrect name space definitions in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am using (sorry am kind of late to the party):

```
  Public Function Serialize(Of YourXMLClass)(ByVal obj As YourXMLClass,
                                                      Optional ByVal omitXMLDeclaration As Boolean = True,
                                                      Optional ByVal omitXMLNamespace As Boolean = True) As String

        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(obj.GetType)
        Using memStream As New MemoryStream()
            Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings() With {
                    .Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                    .Indent = True,
                    .OmitXmlDeclaration = omitXMLDeclaration}

            Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memStream, settings)
                Dim xns As New XmlSerializerNamespaces
                If (omitXMLNamespace) Then xns.Add("", "")
                serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, xns)
            End Using

            Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Function

 Public Function Deserialize(Of YourXMLClass)(ByVal obj As YourXMLClass, ByVal xml As String) As YourXMLClass
        Dim result As YourXMLClass
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(YourXMLClass))

        Using memStream As New MemoryStream()
            Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.ToArray)
            memStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Count)
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

            Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(memStream)
                result = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), YourXMLClass)
            End Using

        End Using
        Return result
    End Function
```