# C# Parse the following XML, not sure how

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xmlreader

I have by example following XML:

```
string xml =
@"<plist version='1.0'>
    <dict>
        <key>DataType</key>
        <string>Employee</string>
        <key>8000</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Id</key>
            <string>8000</string>
            <key>Prename</key>
            <string>Walter</string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Walter Lohner Stans</string>
            <key>Initials</key>
            <string>MAL</string>
        </dict>
        <key>8001</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Id</key>
            <string>8001</string>
            <key>Prename</key>
            <string>Motorrad</string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string> Meierskappel</string>
            <key>Initials</key>
            <string>MAM</string>
        </dict>
        <key>8004</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Id</key>
            <string>8004</string>
            <key>Prename</key>
            <string>Hanspeter</string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Altenbürger AG  Horgen</string>
            <key>Initials</key>
            <string>FH</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>";
```

I would like to get these 3 Employees as a List...

The Class Employee is also defined:

```
//Class
public class Employee
{
    //Properties    
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Prename { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
}
```

How does the parsing work now, if I by example want now to pass the xml to a method and want to have a List (of Type Employees) with these 3 Employees?

I started by doing something like that:

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployees(string xml)
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
    {

    }
}
```

But Actually I don't know how to iterate over all these "dicts" which describe one Employee and generally how to deal with.. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ2XML..It's **COOL**

```
XElement doc=XElement.Parse(".......");

var yourList=doc.Descendants("dict").Descendants("dict").Select(
x=>new Employee
{
Id=x.Elements("string").ElementAt(0).Value,
Prename=x.Elements("string").ElementAt(1).Value,
Name=x.Elements("string").ElementAt(2).Value,
Initials=x.Elements("string").ElementAt(3).Value
}
);
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, nice way, didn't know about! There are 2 things u should change, use: `XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);` (I have no file) and the second, in Elements use string, not key

Comment: "yourList" must be var, u cant do List<Employee>, it gives an error. Cast is also not possible. that was the reason I edited your code, cause its not working so, like it is

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a little like you could benefit from [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) by using the [`Deserialize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk9cbaf1.aspx) method.

Here are a few links showing an example:

[C# - How to xml deserialize object itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081325/c-sharp-how-to-xml-deserialize-object-itself)

[C# Deserialize XML to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085529/c-sharp-deserialize-xml-to-object)

I think that is a possible way to go, otherwise you could parse it into [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) or [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and navigate through the document with XPath. By the way you can use the [`Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) method on `XmlDocument` to load a string of XML

```
    string xmlString = "<root><sub></sub></root>";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(xmlString);
```

or the [`Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) method of `XDocument` to load a string of XML into the object.

```
string str =
    @"<Root>
        <Child>Content</Child>
    </Root>";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
```

Unsure which technique to use, take a look here:

[XDocument or XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument)

I even managed to find an example from Google that will get you started: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169598/Parse-XML-Documents-by-XMLDocument-and-XDocument

Another route is to use the Linq2Xml technique and again here is another question which will show you how it is achieved:

[Reading Xml with XmlReader in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp)

Here is the blog post that answer was based upon:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2007/03/24/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-2.aspx

Comment: thank you! very informative and it makes this question even more interesting as I can use it later as a reference! I solved it now with @Anirudha's method: LINQ2XML, very nice solution

Answer (score 1):

I Suggest you something like this would work for you.

```
string xmlpath = "D:\new\test.xml";   

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlpath);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList employ = root.GetElementsByTagName("Employee");
list<employee> employees=new <employee>();

foreach (XmlElement emp in employ)
{
    string id = emp.GetAttribute("id");
    string name = emp.GetAttribute("name");
    string desc = emp.GetAttribute("Prename");

    Employee e=new employee();
    e.id=id;
    e.Prename =desc;
    e.Name=name;
   employees.add(e);
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but there are 2 things I don't like. The first: I have the XML as string, not as a Document, so I can't use XMLDocument Class. The second: Your not iterating through all Employees, it seems, that ur getting only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
XmlDocument x=new XmlDocument();
x.LoadXml(xml);

foreach (XmlNode x1 in x.SelectNodes("//dict"))
{
    string Id=x1.SelectSingleNode("dict[key[text()='Id']]/string").InnerText;
}
```